# Poolable classes with default custom properties/logic without affecting OOP hierarchy

Tags: c#

I want to make my own pooling library.

By design, I want each poolable class to have a reference of the pool it came from, so ideally whenever the user wants to make a class poolable they'd have to inherit from some `Poolable` base class.

But that seems to immediately have major drawbacks in OOP design. If the user wants to pool a `Player` that inherits from `Sprite` (without making all Sprites poolable), they'd be stuck.

So I guess that's what interfaces should be for, like an `IPoolable`, but then I'm forcing the user to implement boilerplate code for each poolable class (keeping a reference to the original pool was just an example - I want to do other work).

What are my options to let users transform their classes into poolable objects that have custom pooling logic while minimizing the amount of boilerplate they have to write?

Comment: Does the implantation of `Player` need to know what pool it belongs to? Or is the property only going to be accessed by pool-related code?

Answer (score 3):

Make the `Poolable` class generic that has the "value" contained inside it. So you would have something like `Poolable<Player>` which would allow players but not sprites. If the class is abstract then users can still implement custom logic.

`public class PoolablePlayerWrapper : Poolable<Player>`

Answer (score 3):

Your question raises many flags for possible response.

Firstly, "poolable" sounds like an instance-based behavior, not a type-based one. Overall I get the feeling that you're conflating the two in your question.

Secondly:

> a `Player` that inherits from `Sprite`

You're playing fast and loose with your inheritance already. A player is not a subtype of a sprite. A *player sprite* might be; but unless there are particular sprite implementation details that are different for a player (relative to other sprites), this again suggests a conflation of instance-based and type-based behavior.

Thirdly,

> So I guess that's what interfaces should be for, like an IPoolable, but then I'm forcing the user to implement boilerplate code for each poolable class

I'm not sure what you want. You *don't* want the player to receive a premade implementation via its inheritance, and you don't want the player to implement it itself; but you seem to consider inheritance te way to achieve it.

We can discuss things like composition and other ways of structuring your logic, but at the end of the day you're always going to be presented with an option that either requires your class to explicitly acknowledge (and thus implement - even if by composition) the solution, or to implicitly receive it from any of its base types.
To put it differently, when a class implements a certain feature, the only way in which it does not explicitly acknowledge that it does so is by having a base type do it for them instead.

Fourthly;

> What are my options to let **users** transform their **classes** into poolable objects

The bolded words are at odds here. Users don't touch your code, developers do.

There are fringe cases here, e.g. if you're making a programming game or if you're a library builder who builds libraries for developers; but such a scenario would need to be explicitly explained as it leads to certain other considerations. Your question does not reveal any such scenario so I assume this is a cut and dry "the developer develops, the user uses" scenario.

Users can impact *instances* of your types (in regulated ways as defined and allowed by your type); so I get the feeling that this again touches on some conflation between types and instances.

Fifthly, a more direct answer to your question:

What you seem to be dealing with here are customizable behaviors. This is very common in game development, both how developers tend to maintain the codebase over time and how players can alter the way things work during the play session.

The [Entity Component System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system) (ECS) pattern is a tried and true pattern for these use cases.

Essentially, your class (entity) implements a list of behaviors (components). This list can be managed however you like. Maybe the devs predefine which components are loaded as part of the entity's constructor, or maybe the game logic allows for components to be added to that list as the game continues on (for example, a certain enemy might make every weapon they touch a fiery weapon, whereas another enemy does not do this).

This bypasses the need for inheritance (in the way you're talking about it), instead using a well-engineered composition architecture instead.

I'll let you delve into the details of this pattern as this answer cannot comprehensively describe the nuts and bolts of its implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the reference to the pool in a separate data structure and access it through extension methods.

Bearing in mind you have to maintain the pool itself somewhere, you probably already have a data structure you can use. But in this example I create a separate dictionary called `_map`:

```
static class PoolExtensions
{
    static Dictionary<IPoolable, Pool> _map = new ();

    static public GetPool(this IPoolable source)
    {
        return _map[source];
    }

    static public SetPool(this IPoolable source, Pool pool)
    {
        _map[source] = pool;
    }
}


var player = new Player();
player.SetPool(somePool);
Assert.AreEqual(somePool, player.GetPool());
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll chime in from a more language-agnostic perspective. This is a common difficulty in class-based OO languages. The current solutions to this problem (that I can think of) are:

1. Code generation (macros like in C, templates in C++, aspects like AspectJ for Java) to write the boilerplate for you.
2. Multiple inheritence (like in C++ or Ruby), which lets you inherit behaviours, without consuming the sole available superclass "slot"
3. Mixins which let you import the boilerplate (like Ruby's `module`s, `Object.assign` to a prototype in JavaScript)

   - Entity-component systems are like a hand-crafted version of mixins, where you're building the facilities for attaching and running shared behaviours on your own, without support from the language
4. Default implementations of interfaces (like in Rust traits, Swift protocols, or Java/C# interfaces)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the usual solution is to create a class that implements IPoolable and does the logic that makes a class poolable. Then an instance of this class is injected into the class that you want to pool. Delegate methods on the poolable class then do nothing but call the corresponding method on the injected class.

Personally I find this a somewhat clumsy way of implementing multiple inheritance but it is all we have in C# and Java.